# Better code for the case of Erlang

Tags: erlang, case

Given:

```
C = case A of
  undefined ->
    "";
  Value ->
    Value
end
```

How would I express this as a single line?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. In particular, I don't see any messages (what you mean by signals, maybe?) being sent in this code. Can you add more detail about the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the obvious (putting all of that code on one line), you could make a helper function like this:

```
with_default(undefined, D) -> D;
with_default(X, _) -> X.

with_default(X) -> with_default(X, "").
```